# Implementation of Principal Loan Formula Fails to Compile

Tags: c++

This is the formula needed

[image: formula]

I tried coding it but it fails to compile. This is the line:

```
m = ((p * ir)(1 + ir)(1 + ir) / (1 + ir)(1 + ir) - 1) ;
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double p;
double ir;
double l;
double m;
double n;
cout << "What is the principal amount? $" << endl;
cin >> p ;
cout << "What is the interest rate?" << endl;
cin >> ir ;
cout << "What is the loan term, in years?" << endl;
cin >> l ;
n = ir/12 ;
m = ((p * ir)(1 + ir)(1 + ir) / (1 + ir)(1 + ir) - 1) ;
cout << "What is the principal amount? $" << endl;
cin >> p ;
cout << "What is the interest rate?" << endl;
cin >> ir ;
cout << "What is the loan term, in years?" << endl;
cin >> l ;
n = ir/12 ;
m = ((p * ir)(1 + ir)(1 + ir) / (1 + ir)(1 + ir) - 1) ;
cout << "Your annual interest rate is " << ir << " kilnkjnihhjnkograms. 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I take it N = 2.  And what's i?  And what's the compiler error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Implicit multiplication is not supported in many programming languages, including C++. Code such as `(p * ir)(1 + ir)` does not multiply the two expressions.

Comment: @RichardCritten, okay, it's in.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, how can I get the formula in?

Comment: @user9352311 Replace code such as `(p * ir)(1 + ir)` with `(p * ir)*(1 + ir)` for all of the multiplications.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, thanks. It compiles now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile because C++ does not interpret statements like `(a + b)(c + d)` as a multiplication of `(a + b)` by `(c + d)` like it does `(a + b) *
 (c + d)` so substituting `((p * ir)(1 + ir)(1 + ir) / (1 + ir)(1 + ir) - 1)` by `((p * ir) * (1 + ir) * (1 + ir) / (1 + ir) * (1 + ir) - 1)` will make your code compile (you also need to close the quotes on the line before the `return` statement and add a semicolon), though it won't do what you want it to do.
For it to calculate [your formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUBj6.png) with N = 2 you'll need to add parentheses around `(1 + ir) * (1 + ir) - 1` because otherwise it will calculate all of the multiplications and divisions before it subtracts 1 leaving you with the wrong formula. The code that will do what you want it to do is: 
`m = p * ir * (1 + ir) * (1 + ir) / ((1 + ir) * (1 + ir) - 1);` 
Besides that, you also seem to have duplicated part of your code (the part that takes the user inputs) and the variable `n` is never used for anything.